# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)

Tags: python, http, request, response

I want to generate a http request response and i need response code and the data as well i.e. i want to get all the entries related to my query.My code is as follows and i get error whenever i try to extract it in json format.i want to get all the data related to http protocol.Kindly tell me what is the issue with my code.

```
import censys
import requests   
import json
URL ="https://censys.io/ipv4"
UID =""
SECRET = ""  
location = "https"
PARAMS = {'address':location} 
r = requests.get(url = URL,auth=(UID, SECRET),params = PARAMS) 
print(r)  
# extracting data in json format 
data=r.json()
```

**Output**

```html
<Response [200]>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-d8dbe8fb36c9> in <module>()
     17 print(r)
     18 # extracting data in json format
---> 19 data=r.json()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    890                     # used.
    891                     pass
--> 892         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    893 
    894     @property

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)
```

Comment: the response needs to be representable in `json` format, which I think is not in your case.

Comment: What does `print(r.text)` show?